# Duplicate records across all databases based on a column name and a value for that column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a query that:

1. finds all the instances of a column name across all databases
2. duplicates all the records that contain this column name altering the value of the column name based on a value for that column name.

So the inputs would be ColumnName, ColumnNameValue, ColumnNameNewValue

I found this query here http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/find-column-in-all-databases that returns the first part of the query I need but I’m not sure on how to go on about to do part 2…

**EDIT:**

with part 2 what I want to do is find all the records that match an Id  and duplicate them in the same table with a different Id

So for instance I have this table:

```
column1    column2
1          aaa
2          bbb
2          ccc
3          ddd
```

I want the script to find all tables that contain "column1" (this is done in part 1), then find all the records that have a value of "1" for column1, and duplicate the records with a new id "99", so the result would be

```
column1    column2
1          aaa
2          bbb
2          ccc
3          ddd
99         bbb
99         ccc
```

Comment: The problem with getting help for #2 is that you didn't explain what you are trying to do. Try explaining what you want to do more clearly and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options, query the information schema against each database and then union the results together

```
select * from db1.information_Schema.columns
union all
select * from db2.information_Schema.columns
```

or use the undocumented sp_MSforeachdb function

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'select * from information_Schema.columns'
```

Of course, being undocumented, it could change, stop working or not work correctly to begin with, so you would need to accept that risk.